# I can't use create-react-app on my system again

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I can't do create-react-app my-app.  I keep getting that error..  I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Does the log show any other error messages?

Comment: No just what is in that screenshot

Comment: Would you try `npx` to run the latest `create-react-app` like `npx create-react-app learning-react`? the CRA could be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

i actually cleared my npm cache and everything became fine

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to resolve by force clearing the cache.
If it's not working then delete everything from `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`

You can also create react application by following command.
`npx create-react-app demo-react`